# Waveshare 3.5 LCD screen not working

Tags: pi-4, lcd

I have two 3.5 inch waveshare RPi screens ([https://www.amazon.com/Resistive-Screen-IPS-Resolution-Controller/dp/B07V9WW96D/ref=sr_1_1?crid=174003FCA1ORU&keywords=waveshare+3.5+RPi&qid=1657034424&sprefix=waveshare+3.5+rp%2Caps%2C168&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07V9WW96D)) and I can't get them to work.

I have a standard RaspberryPi OS (release 2022-04-04) installed onto an ssd disk using Raspberry Pi imager v1.7.2 (RPi model 4b). The waveshare screen connects right ontop of the RPi board.

The LCD screen is just lit but blank.

I followed the instructions on the manufacturers wiki https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A) to install the (touch?) drivers.

After successful driver install the RPi rebooted automatically. The little waveshare screen still didn't work (just lit, but blank as before) and now the other screen (HDMI-connected) didn't work either, the monitor says "non-optimal resolution". So apparently the drivers changed the resolution output but the little screen still isn't working. And now I can't use my big screen either.

I tried unplugging the HDMI screen (thinking perhaps it can only run one screen at a time) but still the waveshare screen shows nothing.

I've tried both screens I bought, same behavior, so shouldn't be a hardware glitch.

The manufacturer also recommend using their own image for a linux dist with drivers pre-installed, at their link with the text/title **3.5inch RPi LCD(A) -2020-08-20-raspios-buster-armhf-full** however, that link, which goes to the url https://1drv.ms/u/s!At1XVmt1PVrlgQMnNL_rKl_jr41j?e=g3uasY takes me to a Microsoft Onedrive page saying that the link is no longer working.

I don't really want to have to use a certain dist of linux to operate the screen, but it seems they no longer provide it anyways (a bit unprofessional to link to a shared Onedrive file eh?).

What should I do? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to contact Waveshare support?

Comment: Yes I'm in contact with them. So far no luck

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look at those photos at amazon...

one of the photos shows its waveshare 3.5" **B**

so **3.5inch RPi LCD(B)** is the image you need.

there are links to working images here:
[waveshare](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(B))

in a terminal type:

```
git clone https://github.com/waveshare/LCD-show.git
cd LCD-show/
chmod +x LCD35B-show
 ./LCD35B-show
```

this will install the waveshare files needed for the display.

check '/boot/config.txt', it should now contain
'dtoverlay=waveshare35b'

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/123595)